# passing object to callback function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am recently working on small chat module , which require continuously checking the server for new message.

I am sending a ajax request to a server , and the server hold's the connection until new message is found(long polling).

Code :

```
var chatController = function(){
 
//other variable declaration

/**
*  Ajax call to monitor the new message , on complete of ajax call sending other call
*/

this.checkNewMessage = function(){
  console.log(this); // placed this for debugging purpose
       $.ajax({
         url : SITEURL.CHECK_MESSAGE,
         data : this.currrentUserDetails,
         dataType : 'json' ,
         cache    : false,
         success  :(function(obj){
            //temp = obj;
            return obj.parseNewMessageResponse;
         })(this),
         complete: (function(obj){
            //temp = obj;
            return obj.checkNewMessage;
         })(this),  
       });
       
     
};

  // other function and variable

});
```

When i tried to call

```
var mainController = new chatController();
mainController.checkNewMessage();
```

**Problem**

What i thought was that i would be able to send continuous single request to server, but to my surprise I only could send 2 ajax request one after the other.

**My Debugging**

When i tried to debug , i traced out that for the first call `this` object being passed points to the `chatController`

```
         complete: (function(obj){
            return obj.checkNewMessage;
         })(this),     // this here point to chatController object
```

For the second time `this` object being passed points to the `ajax object`

```
         complete: (function(obj){
            return obj.checkNewMessage;
         })(this),     // this here point to ajax object
```

I am using JavaScript closure to pass the `chatController` object to `complete` parameter of jquery

So what i want is way to pass parameter to `jQuery` `complete` function  so that it's point to my original reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: you can define "this" into variable and then use it. like var $thisChatController = this;

Comment: @SohilDesai can you show me some example, thanks

Comment: @Parfait i want to pass a same object function in the callback

Comment: you can implement it with Signal R , this is a sample of chat application in .net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524066/SignalR-Simple-Chat-Application-in-Csharp if you are using some other language you can integrate it with that too......

Comment: [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) would be your friend here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There are various posible [cross-browser](/questions/tagged/cross-browser) solutions

### You can use [**`$.proxy`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

*In my opinion, the best practice.*

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: $.proxy(function(json) {
         // `this` refers to the second argument of `$.proxy`
    }, this)
});
```

### You can set the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    context: this,
    success: function(json) {
         // `this` refers to the value of `context`
    }
});
```

### Or use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function(json) {
         // `this` refers to ajax request, use self instead
         $(self).dosomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least four different ways to solve the issue of not calling your method with the right context from your `success` and `complete` handlers.

1. Use the `context` argument for `$.ajax()` so that `this` in your success handler will be what you want it to be so you can then call your method.
2. Use `.bind()` to create a new function stub that calls your method with the right context.
3. Save the value of `this` into a local variable so you can reference that variable when you need it in a stub function.
4. Use jQuery's cross browser version of `.bind()` which is called [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/).

I will offer you some examples of each.

First, the `context` option for `$.ajax()`:

```
this.checkNewMessage = function(){
  console.log(this); // placed this for debugging purpose
       $.ajax({
         context: this,
         url : SITEURL.CHECK_MESSAGE,
         data : this.currrentUserDetails,
         dataType : 'json' ,
         cache    : false,
         success  : function(data) {
             this.parseNewMessageResponse(data);
         },
         complete : function(data) {
             this.checkNewMessage();
         }
       });
};
```

Then, using `.bind()`.

```
this.checkNewMessage = function(){
  console.log(this); // placed this for debugging purpose
       $.ajax({
         url : SITEURL.CHECK_MESSAGE,
         data : this.currrentUserDetails,
         dataType : 'json' ,
         cache    : false,
         success  : this.parseNewMessageResponse.bind(this),
         complete : this.checkNewMessage.bind(this)
       });
};
```

Then, using a saved copy of `this`:

```
this.checkNewMessage = function(){
     var self = this;
     console.log(this); // placed this for debugging purpose
       $.ajax({
         url : SITEURL.CHECK_MESSAGE,
         data : this.currrentUserDetails,
         dataType : 'json' ,
         cache    : false,
         success  : function(data) {
             self.parseNewMessageResponse(data);
         },
         complete : function(data) {
             self.checkNewMessage();
         }
       });
};
```

And finally with jQuery's `.proxy():

```
this.checkNewMessage = function(){
  console.log(this); // placed this for debugging purpose
       $.ajax({
         url : SITEURL.CHECK_MESSAGE,
         data : this.currrentUserDetails,
         dataType : 'json' ,
         cache    : false,
         success  : $.proxy(this.parseNewMessageResponse, this),
         complete : $.proxy(this.checkNewMessage, this)
       });
};
```

If you don't need IE8 support or you're fine with installing a polyfill for `.bind()`, then the `.bind()` option is my favorite because it just seems the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to define a reference to your original **this** so you can access it from another context. Check this simple example:

```
(function(){
  var _self = this;

  function changeColor($element, color){
    $element.css("background-color", color)
  }

  $(".recolor-btn").click(function(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Color/GetRandom",
      success: function(color){
        _self.changeColor($(self), color);
      }
    });
  });

})();
```